# CSS in my header, the menu overlaps the logo

Tags: html, css

my page is running at bee-barcelona.herokuapp.com

I have the problem that the menu is running into the logo, once I resize the browser or open the page on the tablet. I want to clear it with CSS. How do I have to set it up that the elements don't overlap?

This is my current CSS for the header:

```
header {
  background-color: #000;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555), to(#222));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #555, #222);
  color: #FFFF00;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding: 22px 100px;
  #logo {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  a {
    color: #ffc400;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 18px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    li {
      float: left;
      padding: 2px 10px;
      border-right: solid 2px #6F6F6F;
      &.last {
        border-right: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
.language {
    float:right;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

And this is the HTML for the header:

```
<h1 id='logo'>
  <%= link_to Refinery::Core.site_name, refinery.root_path %>
</h1>
<%= Refinery::Pages::MenuPresenter.new(refinery_menu_pages, self).to_html %>
<div class="language">
<%= link_to image_tag("cat.png"),refinery.url_for(:locale => :ca) %>
<%= link_to image_tag("esp.png"),refinery.url_for(:locale => :es) %>
<%= link_to image_tag("eng.png"),refinery.url_for(:locale => :en) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is overlapping the logo because it's absolutely positioned. Try using floats instead:

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

header ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi myarjouri,
The look and feel is almost the same, but I can still pull the text over the logo. Do I have to use some "clear" option? Thx

Comment: You already use a clearfix on nav, you should keep that. What borwser are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox and Safari

Comment: Hi Myajouri! 
Sorry, forgot to precompile the assets, my server reacted wrong! Now it is working like a charm. Thanks for this helpful answer!